# Tests coverage for Solana programs?

Tags: tests, test-bpf

It is important in development of anything (including Solana programs) to be able to track code coverage.

Is there a way to get the coverage for BPF/SBF-based tests?

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but if you can run your tests with `solana-program-test` https://docs.rs/solana-program-test/latest/solana_program_test/ and use `prefer_bpf(false)`, then the tests will run all in Rust, so you can do coverage reports, ie:

```
#[test]
fn my_test() {
    let mut program_test = solana_program_test::ProgramTest::default();
    program_test.prefer_bpf(false);
    program_test.add_program(
        "my-program",
        my_program_id,
        solana_program_test::processor!(my_programs_process_instruction),
    );
}
```